# Laravel Auth::guard('api')->user() returning null

Tags: laravel

I am creating REST API with laravel 5.6. For that I am using the default laravel api_token method for authentication.

I made a get user profile api like this

```
public function getUserProfile(){
        if( Auth::guard('api')->check() ){
            $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
            return response()->json([
                'data' => $user->toArray(),
                'success' => true
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['errors' =>  array('status' => 401, 'detail' => 'Authentication error.'),'success' => false], 200);
        }
    }
```

Route is like this:-

```
Route::get('getuser', 'Api\Auth\LoginController@getUserProfile');
```

This is working perfectly on my localhost.But when I put it to a server subdomain it returing unauthenticated every time.

Basically the authentication failure everytime.If anyone have any suggestion that will be very help full for me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Route::get('getuser', 'Api\Auth\LoginController@getUserProfile')->middleware('auth:api');`?

Comment: not working with this.

Comment: The issue I found the server is not receiving the header information "Authorization"

Comment: Are you sure your front end URL and back END url are from the same domain (or subdmain in your case)?

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your api routes file (api.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api',]], function () {
Route::get('getuser', 'Api\Auth\LoginController@getUserProfile');
});
```